# What does {1:C} in C# mean when found inside a string?

Tags: c#

For example,

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}\n earned:{1:C}\n". salariedEmployee, salariedEmployee.earnings());
```

I have found previous questions that explains what `{0}` means. however, it doesn't explain what {1:C} means.

Comment: @Wabbit 1) Just put what you need into [google](https://www.google.pl/#q=Console+WriteLine) and click the first link 2) find the [interesting overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/586y06yf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the function you're using 3) read about format strings in the "Remarks" section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The format specifier `{1:C}` means Currency.

Refs:

- [String Formatting in C#](http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/)
- [Format Specifiers in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/e514eeby.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, these references will do.

Answer (score 1):

{1} is the parameter number to be substituted (in your case, the value of salariedEmployee.earnings()). I assume you already knew this from your comment on {0}.

The ":C" part of the string format token specifies that the value will be formatted as a currency. This will format the value to be appropriate for whatever current cultures currency is (so in the US it will format the value to be $0.00).

Its equivalent to saying salariedEmployee.earnings().ToString("C") (which is actually an overload of ToString from the IFormattable interface).

More information can be found on the MSDN documentation for string.Format (and the links that lead on from there) available at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx.

Answer (score 0):

{x:yy} is what is known as a format specifier. A couple of Framework methods like String.Format, Console.Write/Console.WriteLine, and int.ToString, have built in support for using these specifiers. .NET has really good support for it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx and can generally format numbers, dates and things according to the right locale with little effort.

The C stands for currency as others have pointed out.